# WxPython, Collapsible Pane containing Scrolled Window

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to create a Collapsible Pane, that is also scrollable, for when the contained button-list is larger than the screen. So I put a ScrolledWindow inside the Pane - and got this error:

> Gtk-WARNING: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkScrolledWindow to a GtkExpander, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkExpander can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type wxPizza

What, they don't like Pizza? :) My first reading of that, makes me think they are incompatible widgets, as both are presumably of type GtkExpander. But this question - [Scrollbars not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851247/scrolledwindow-not-showing-scollbars-when-used-with-pycollapsiblepane) - appears to use both widget-types. With some differences - first, they're putting the CollapsiblePane *inside* the ScrolledWindow, and second, it's actually a PyCollapsiblePane, from the AGW library of WxPython.

So is it possible, with some combination of widgets, to have a collapsible object, that when expanded, contains a scrolling list of objects? And if so, how? Or are the two widgets just incompatible (in that order)?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a minimal, workable example to give us something to work with.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, well, rubber-ducking for the win... :) I finally got around to trying to extract/condense a code sample - and it worked. (Mostly - lotta weirdness, but it managed to have a scrolling panel inside a collapsing panel). For the solution, it turns out that CollapsiblePanes have an `inner_pane` that you're supposed to add sub-widgets to. Wups.

Comment: It's often the way with these things. Once you sit down to sort out the example, the solution rears its ugly head, often resulting in a "Why didn't I see that!" moment. Seeing as you've gone through the effort, why not post a self answer to your question. Regards.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, yep. And I was about 50/50 on deleting the question, versus answering it, but you broke the tie. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Turns out that a Collapsible-Pane has an inner-panel that is intended to be used for children.

```
class BadCollapsingPanel(wx.CollapsiblePane):
def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(parent, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
    self.parent = parent
    self.inner_pane = self.GetPane()
    self.inner_pane.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    # self.very_bad_panel = ScrollingPanel(self)  # Breaks
    self.very_bad_panel = ScrollingPanel(self.inner_pane)  # Works
```